# A non-local equation on Laplace transforms.

Tags: probability, laplace-transform, functional-equations

I wish to find all probability distributions $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^+$ whose Laplace transform:

$\varphi(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zx} \mu(dx), z \geqslant 0,$

solves the equation:

$\varphi(z) = \beta \varphi(z) g(z) +  (1-\beta) \frac{\varphi(z+1)}{\varphi(1)},$

where $g$ again is the Laplace transform of some given distribution on $\mathbb R^+$

This equation characterizes the fixed point in distribution of some probabilistic model for the balance between selection and mutation. The difficulty comes from the non-local term (the fact that the equation mixes $z$ and $z+1$)

All comments are welcome !

Comment: knowing $\varphi$ on the integers will give you the moments of $e^{-X}$ where $X$ has distribution $\mu$

Comment: also, $\varphi$ solution implies  $z \mapsto e^{-za} \varphi(z)$ is a solution

Comment: Actually these two remarks combined answer the question. I will close it when the bounty ends up